# Android refresh Recyclerview adapter on Dialog

Tags: android

in some part of my application i have `RecyclerView` on custom Dialog, but in that when i set data, keep in Recyclerview and dont refresh with new data, for example this below code is my show custom Dialog:

```
transferred_to_user_history.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        List<Transactions> transactionsHistoryList = Collections.emptyList();
        transactionsHistoryList = realm.where(Transactions.class)
                .equalTo("toUser", username)
                .equalTo("destinationEwalletId", latestChosenUserEwallet)
                .findAll();
        Log.e("transactionsHistoryList", transactionsHistoryList.size() + "");
        if (getChosenTransferredHistory == null)
            getChosenTransferredHistory =
                    new GetChosenEwalletTransferredHistory(ActivityTransferMoney.this)
                    .setData(transactionsHistoryList);

        getChosenTransferredHistory.setOnTransactiontHistory(new GetChosenEwalletTransferredHistory.IOnChooseTransactionHistory() {
            @Override
            public void getItem(EwalletsHistory item) {
                getChosenTransferredHistory.dismissDialog();
                getChosenTransferredHistory = null;
            }
        });
        getChosenTransferredHistory.showDialog();
    }
});
```

if `transactionsHistoryList.size()` variable was `1` in first attach and show data on RecyclerView and after dismissDialog and reattach with empty result, i have attached data in last showDialog,

First showDialog :

```
transactionsHistoryList.size(): 1
```

Second showDialog :

```
transactionsHistoryList.size(): 0
```

in second part i have some data on recylerview, but `transactionsHistoryList.size()` is `0`

**My Custom Dialog:**

```
public GetChosenEwalletTransferredHistory(ActivityTransferMoney context) {
    this.context = context;
    realm = realm.getDefaultInstance();

    dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.theme_dialog);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_user_transferred_history);

    transferred_history = (RecyclerView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.transferred_history);

    List<Transactions> r = new ArrayList<>();

    transferred_history.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    adapter = new GetLatestUserTransferredHistoryAdapter(context, r);
    transferred_history.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public GetChosenEwalletTransferredHistory setData(List<Transactions> result) {
    adapter.setData(result);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return this;
}
```

**My Adapter:**

```
public class GetLatestUserTransferredHistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GetLatestUserTransferredHistoryAdapter.EwalletHistoryViewHolder> {

    public static IOnItemClickListener iOnItemClickListener;
    List<Transactions> list = Collections.emptyList();
    Context context;

    public GetLatestUserTransferredHistoryAdapter(Context context, List<Transactions> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public EwalletHistoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View                     v      = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.latest_transactions_items, parent, false);
        EwalletHistoryViewHolder holder = new EwalletHistoryViewHolder(v);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EwalletHistoryViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.transaction_report_row.setText(list.get(position).getMoney() + list.get(0).getCurrencySymbol() + " on: " + list.get(position).getCreatedAt());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public void setData(List<Transactions> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Comment: getChosenTransferredHistory = null; why are you doing this?

Comment: @ColdFire its for create force new instance for Dialog, when i see adapter dont refresh i thought i must create new instance for dialog

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setData(List<Transactions> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

change to:

```
public void setData(List<Transactions> list) {
    this.list.clear();
    this.list.addAll(list);
}
```

lists aren't updated with `=`